# Do more formats in @font-face determine more http requests?

Tags: css, font-face, page-load-time

Consider a similar css code:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'MyFont';
    src: url('../fonts/MyFont.eot');
    src: local('Proxima'), url('../fonts/MyFont.woff') format('woff'), url('../fonts/MyFont.ttf') format('truetype'), url('../fonts/MyFont.svg') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

Does this code determine more HTTP requests to download all the formats or does the browser choose the best supported format?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nope, browser will choose one compatible format. Feel free to add as many sources as you like :)

Comment: thank you, is this stated anywhere on the w3c specification or something?

Answer (score 1):

No, only one will be used. You can test it for example with firebug or google console and check the list of all requests that has been made (network tab)

Comment: true. How can I check if this is tha case also for IE? :-)

Comment: i'm on linux currently and I do not have access to IE but isn't there something like "developer tools" ?