# Will multiple @font-face formats slow download?

Tags: css, font-face

I'm developing a website and using @font-face for typography (because the exact font required isn't available as a webfont). I used [Font Squirrel's @font-face generator](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fontface/generator) to create their recommended formats, which include different formats for maximum cross-browser compatibility, and used their sample CSS:

```
@font-face {
font-family: 'playfair_displayregular';
src: url('playfair-display-webfont.eot');
src: url('playfair-display-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
     url('playfair-display-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
     url('playfair-display-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
     url('playfair-display-webfont.svg#playfair_displayregular') format('svg');
font-weight: normal;
font-style: normal;

}
```

My question is, are browsers going to try and download all the different formats, or does each browser just load one for it to use?

Comment: In my experience, the browser will stop downloading one font-face once it successfully downloads and parses one format, or runs out of choices. Haven't seen a browser stupid enough to download multiple formats of the same font-face, unless the first attempted format turns out to be corrupt.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13609119/if-multiple-sources-are-listed-in-an-font-face-are-all-of-them-loaded-on-the-c and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10338152/do-more-formats-in-font-face-determine-more-http-requests, among others

Comment: @BoltClock The accepted answer at that duplicate question is wrong, based on Paul Irish's research at [Bulletproof @ font-face syntax](http://paulirish.com/2009/bulletproof-font-face-implementation-syntax/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Under certain circumstances, some browsers will download multiple formats of the same font-face.

A thorough explanation can be found at [Bulletproof @font-face syntax](http://paulirish.com/2009/bulletproof-font-face-implementation-syntax/), but the gist of it is that FontSquirrel is doing all the hard work for you and their syntax implements the the best syntax and prevents multiple resources from being downloaded.

The article is worth reading and also provides links to more information.

Comment: @Plummer: That seems to be a reason to upvote the question rather than the answer, since the OP used FontSquirrel which prompted this question to begin with.

Comment: @Ghodmode, I did both, foo.